# Enable an event listener when the context menu closes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code in order to remove my event listener on my web page when the context menu is opened:

```
var func = function(event)
{
    if(event.button != 2) //For left click
    {
        //Some code
    }
    else //For right click
    {
        window.removeEventListener("click", something, false);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to enable this event listener when the context menu is closed. I don't know if there is something in JavaScript (not jQuery) to tell me when a contextmenu is closed or something like that.
Do you know?

Comment: @Bergi Yes but I don't have to use jquery like in this subject

Comment: That doesn't matter - everything that is possible with jQuery can be done in native javascript. And the answer was: No, there's no native `close` event, you have to work around.

Comment: I see, so I have to work around like you say.